# How To: Best way to run a threaded loop with a UI update at the end of each?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0

an architectural question here.

I have a List (selected via a listview) that needs to be sent to a webservice and created in the database.  I want to be able to update one at a time then update a progress bar, listview and local List with the returned ID without locking up the uithread (although i'll have lock the listview/search controls etc they just need to be able to complete other task in different forms).

At the minute i've considered the following (new to most)

Background worker - the only problem here is that the progressChanged only returns an int so i'd find it difficult to return all the information I need.

Tasks - i'm using these at the minute when all I need to return a single object and then process that information (like getting list from local database and then populating listview and that works well). I can't figure out how to spawn a thread that in turn does a loop and updates the UI Thread at the end of each pass.

parallel.foreach - don't think this would be suitable with the web services element.

All the stuff i've tried so far, either locks the UI or gets cross thread exceptions.

I guess i'm looking for something that allows me to do this

```
createUsers(ref List<users> _users)
{
    foreach(user _u in _users)
    {
        //call webservice and update - it returns an ID or null
        string newID = webCreate(_u);
        if (newID != null)
        {
            ListViewItem lvi = listview1.FindText(_u.ListID);
            lvi.SubItems[5].Text = newID;
            _u.newID = newID;
        }
        else
        {
            lvi.SubItems[5].Text = "Error";
        }
        progressbar.value++
    }
}
```

There just seems to be so many options in .net 4.0 for threading I just can't think which one will best serve me.  Any pointers would be great.

Thanks, Pete.

Comment: Just as an aside, why are you using `ref` here, when you're never assigning a new value to `_users`?

Comment: I update the value here _u.newID = newID;

Comment: Call the BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(Int32, Object) and pass the information (an instance of a class) as the object parameter. At the BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged event hook, check for the ProgressChangedEventArgs parameter, which will contain the UserState property with the class you passed.

Comment: Hmmm this might be preferable actually, bit less hassle than creating a load of delegates if I have to replicate this model on other forms.  Unfortunately I have to go out to a wedding now so I'll have to try this later. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your create users is run in a separate thread. Have your form, have an updatestatusbar

```
delegate void updStatusbar(int i);
public UpdateStatusBar(int i)
{
  if (Statusbar1.InvokeRequred)
  {
    updStatusbar c = UpdateStatusBar;
    this.Invoke(c,new object[] {i});
  }
  else
    Statusbar1.value=i;
  }
}
```

Now you can call updatestatusbar from anywhere, thread or otherwise and it sorts itself out.

Comment: Hmm I guess I can apply this logic to the listview as well. Let me give it a try :)

Comment: Yep. For any updates to your form. If you do this, whatever thread stuff you end up working with or not, you know it will always update.

Comment: +1, but note that calling the UI thread lots of times (i.e. for each work item) quickly becomes a performance problem.

Comment: Yes it is better if you can bulk update. However, it does mean with delegates you can update absolutely anything.

However, if you're just updating progress, you can often poll for the counter with a property.

Comment: Hi guys,  just an update, managed to get both of the recommended methods working, i'll test to see which ones faster and go with that one :)